# Conway's game of life with C. Command terminated when calling function to generate new generation and update "board"

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I'm writing Conway's game of life in C. I understand that the rules of the game are:

1. Any live cell with 2 or 3 live neighbours survives.
2. Any dead cell with 3 live neighbours becomes a live cell.
3. All other live cells die in the next generation.

'#' symbolises a live cell and '.' symbolises a dead one

The code to my function to generate and update the universe "board" for every generation is written below. It takes in the universe (A 2d array which I dynamically allocated memory for in the main function), the no of rows and no of columns of the 2d array. All other functions (such as alive_neighbour) are correct and the program runs smoothly to the point this function is called. Afterwhich the terminal just prints "command terminated". I can't seem to figure out which part of the function causes the program to crash. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
 void next_generation(char **universe, long row, long column)
 {
     for (long i = 1; i <= (row - 1); i += 1) {
         for (long j = 1; j <= (column - 1); j += 1) {

         //a = no of alive neighbours surrounding universe[i][j]
             long a = alive_neighbour(universe, i, j);

             if (universe[i][j] == '#') {
                 if (a == 2 || a == 3) {
                     universe[i][j] = '#';
                 }
             }
             else if (universe[i][j] == '.') {
                 if (a == 3) {
                     universe[i][j] = '#';
                 }
             }
             else {
                 universe[i][j] = '.';
             }         
    }
     }
 }
```

```
long alive_neighbour(char **universe, long row, long column)
 {
     long count = 0;
     for (long i = -1; i <= 1; i += 1) {
         for (long j = -1; j <= 1; j += 1) {
                 if (universe[row + i][column + j] == '#') {
                     count += 1;
                 }
         }
     }
     if (universe[row][column] == '#') {
         count -= 1;
     }
     return count;
}
```

How I declared universe in the main function:

```
universe = (char **)malloc((size_t) row * sizeof(char *));
for (long i = 0; i < row; i += 1) {
         universe[i] = (char *)malloc((size_t) column * sizeof(char));
 }
```

Comment: `for (long i = 1; (i <= row);` Indexing in C is zero based. You can try to battle this fact but you will lose.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I looped from 1 to (row-1) and (column-1) because the cells on the edges of the board are always dead

Comment: How is `universe` (as in, the array you pass into that parameter) declared and allocated?

Comment: Assuming the array dimension is row x column, you have index overruns at the upper end.

Comment: @Henry Oh yeah I realised I have to subtract 2 from row and column instead. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You just need to use `<` in the loop condition, rather than `<=`. Using `<` should become your second nature. Otherwise you will keep getting these off by one errors. Everyone is using `<`, that's no accident.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Alright will take note. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Re : “ because the cells on the edges of the board are always dead” - this is a very strong statement. Can you back it up?

Comment: I believe you algorithm is not correct. The state of you cells depend on the new state of the cells in the row above, why it should consider previous state.